# Question related to Qualcomm's Qcar sdk

Tags: augmented-reality

Can Anyone suggest how we can capture the an image after 3d augmentation in augmented reality. That is once we detected the tracker which is a requirement of Qcar sdk and placed a 3d texture over it. Then i need to capture this image with 3d textured augmented. Any suggestions would be helpful in my research.

Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't done this, but apparently it's possible using glReadPixels

Here's a description
https://ar.qualcomm.at/arforums/showthread.php?t=666
& an example
https://ar.qualcomm.at/arforums/showthread.php?t=427